# what is the priority for static block in java?

Tags: java

```
public class Static
{
    static
    {
        int x = 5;
    }

    static int x,y;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        x--; myMethod();
        System.out.println(x + y + ++x);
    }

    public static void myMethod()
    {
        y = x++ + ++x;
    }
}
```

Could you please somebody help me here why it is displaying out put is 3?

Comment: Should we tag this as `homework`? :)

Comment: @Jonathan M I don't think so since it's not actually an excercise in tracing but rather a fundamental misunderstanding in scoping & naming.

Comment: Damn this question is good. When I manually calculate it, without computer, my result is 0.

Comment: @ArtB: Yeah, it looked like the kind of thing a CS prof would give to the class saying, "What's wrong with this?" :)

Comment: Well in my experience this is the kind of detail that CS profs don't actually know since it is too practical. That said I presumed university; it very well could be college or highschool homework.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
  static
  {
        int x = 5;
  }
```

You redeclare `x` here, making it a locally scoped variable (not a class member).  This assignment will have no affect whatsoever, regardless of when it is run.

Now, you asked about the static block and that's what I answered.  If you are confused about why a value of 3 is outputted even assuming that assignment doesn't take place, then this becomes a question about the increment operators (`x++` and `++x`).

### Full explanation

I like Paulo's explanation quite a bit but let's just see if we can simplify the code.  To start, let's forget about making `x` and `y` a static field (making them local, initialized to the default for a static int: 0) and inline `myMethod()`:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
x--;
y = x++ + ++x;
System.out.println(x + y + ++x);
```

First we should eliminate complex expressions.  We can do that by extracting each sub-expression into a temporary variable *in the correct order* (expressions are evaluated left-to-right):

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
x--;

int yOperand1 = x++;
int yOperand2 = ++x;
y = yOperand1 + yOperand2;

int resultOperand1 = x;
int resultOperand2 = y;
int resultOperand3 = ++x;
int result = resultOperand1 + resultOperand2 + resultOperand3;
System.out.println(result);
```

Now we can label the value of `x`, `y` and any temporary variables at each step:

```
int x = 0, y = 0;           //x: 0   y: 0
x--;                        //x: -1  y: 0

int yOperand1 = x++;        //x: 0   y: 0  yOperand1: -1
int yOperand2 = ++x;        //x: 1   y: 0  yOperand1: -1  yOperand2: 1
y = yOperand1 + yOperand2;  //x: 1   y: 0

int resultOperand1 = x;     //x: 1   y: 0  resultOperand1: 1
int resultOperand2 = y;     //x: 1   resultOperand1: 1  resultOperand2: 0
int resultOperand3 = ++x;   //x: 2   resultOperand1: 1  resultOperand2: 0  resultOperand3: 2
int result = resultOperand1 + resultOperand2 + resultOperand3; //result: 3
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your static block has a local variable named `x`, it does not change the static variable with the same name.

In general, `static { ... }` blocks will be merged by the compiler with the initializers of static variables in the order they are in the code, and executed on class initialization. (In bytecode, this is a static `<clinit>` method.)

In your program the following occurs:

- the static variables `x` and `y` are initialized with their default values (`0`).
- the static block with its local variable is executed, this has no effect on the rest of the program.
- the main method will execute.

  - it sets `x = -1`.
  - it invokes `myMethod()`.

    - `myMethod` will twice increment `x` (from `-1` to `0` to `1`), and set `y` to `0` (the value before the first incrementing + the value after the second one).
  - it adds `x` (`1`), `y` (`0`) and the value after increasing `x` again (`2`), and prints the result (`3`).

Comment: So, in the expression `x++ + ++x`, the first increment has no effect on x because of the second increment?

Comment: @Martijn: It has an effect.  But the value passed into the addition is `-1`, not 0.  Then x is 0 and incremented to 1 with 1 being passed as the second operand to the addition.  So it is resolved to `y = -1 + 1`.

Answer (score 1):

`Static.x` starts with the value 0 since `{int x = 5;}` creates a new variable that is only visible within the `static` block. Since *that* `x` is never used it does nothing. If you removed it you should be able to trace through and see why your answer is what it is. :)

What you want is either to make the contents of the static block an assignment rather than a declaration ( ie `static{ x = 5; }`) or to assign `x` the value 5 at declaration `static int x = 5;`.